# How to converting address into Lat Long coordinates in google map SDK?

Tags: ios, google-maps-sdk-ios

only find API coordinates to address in class GMSGeocoder (API:reverseGeocodeCoordinate). why NO API address to coordinates?
Dose anyone know this? thanks lots

Answer (score 0):

You may want to use their API instead like below. Just pass in the address and the key you would get from the Google Developers Console.

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=1600+Amphitheatre+Parkway,+Mountain+View,+CA&key=API_KEY

from: [The Google Geocoding API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/intro)

Comment: thanks. i'm using IOS google-Map-SDK. except your mentioned. Is there a API in IOS google-Map-SDK

Comment: I quickly gone through the documentation but didn't find what you need. You may browse it again to be sure.
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios/reference/interface_g_m_s_geocoder.html#details

I have used the WS API in my answer I think because I had the same issue as you have now.